# How to remove spacing between buttons in Unity3D?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, button, layout, spacing

I'm creating buttons programmatically in a game I'm designing in Unity. I instantiate the button prefab and parent them to the Panel object on the canvas. I've set the Panel to have a Horizontal Layout Group with the following properties:

[image]

I've added the following components to the button prefab to achieve the look I require:

[image]

After doing all this here's the result I end up with:

[image]

Therefore, my question is, how can I remove the spacing between each of the buttons? The buttons are supposed to be right next to each other (but not overlapping) to look like a sentence. The reason why I've got separate buttons is so that the user needs to click the correct 2 letter characters in the sentence (in the above example is the letters `ar`). I've set the spacing on the properties to `0` and checked/unchecked the various options but no luck!

I've unchecked the width option for Child Force Expand on both the Panel and Button objects but the sentence looks all crammed.... how could I ensure the buttons sit neatly one after the other (i.e not overlapping)?

[image]

Code relating to comment below:

```
 for (int i = 0; i < letterArray.Length; i++)
        {
            button = (GameObject)Instantiate(buttonPrefab);
            button.transform.SetParent(buttonPanel.transform, false);
            button.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text = letterArray[i];

            FitButtonWidthToText();
        }
    }

    public void FitButtonWidthToText()
    {
        int widthOfTheText = 0;
        CharacterInfo characterInfo;
        foreach (char c in button.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().text)
        {
            button.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().font.GetCharacterInfo(c, out characterInfo, button.GetComponentInChildren<Text>().fontSize);
            widthOfTheText += characterInfo.advance;
        }
        buttonTransform.sizeDelta = new Vector2(widthOfTheText, buttonTransform.sizeDelta.y);
    }
```

Answer (score 5):

Uncheck **Child Force Expand: Width**

From [the docs](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/script-HorizontalLayoutGroup.html):

> *Child Force Expand:* Whether to force the child layout elements to expand to fill additional available space.

Checking *width* (resp. *height*) will have the elements fill the available space horizontally (resp. *vertically*).

---

*EDIT:* Do **not** put a *Content Size Fitter* on children of a *Layout Group*. More info: [Making UI elements fit the size of their content](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/HOWTO-UIFitContentSize.html).

*Based on our discussion:* So the steps described in the above link **only work on the most recent versions** of Unity. If you are stuck with a more mature version, you may keep the *ContentSizeFitter* to achieve the desired result, with the gotcha that if you change the size of a child element, **the layout won’t update automatically** as you would expect. To remedy this, you can **force a partial re-layout** like explained by *Stephan-B* in [this thread](https://forum.unity.com/threads/force-immediate-layout-update.372630/):

> The following function [LayoutRebuilder.ForceRebuildLayoutImmediate](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/UI.LayoutRebuilder.ForceRebuildLayoutImmediate.html) should prove useful. Instead of forcing a rebuild of all the Canvases which can have a significant performance impact, you can call this function on the root (top parent) object in the hierarchy the contains the layout component affecting the object in question.

Comment: Thank you for that. I've unchecked the width option on both the panel and button objects but they all cram together though? How can I ensure they all sit neatly one after the next? I've pasted a screenshot of the issue in my original post.

Comment: Well, increase the *Spacing* (and also make sure that the bounds of your words' RecTransforms are correct)

Comment: Have you tried increasing the value of *Spacing*? Did it work?

Comment: Is there any way I can just make sure the buttons sit one after the other?

Comment: Increasing the spacing worked for one of the sentences but not for the others! :(

Comment: Sorry I'm new to Unity so not quite sure what you mean by `(and also make sure that the bounds of your words' RecTransforms are correct)`? The buttons will be different widths depending on the actual word

Comment: remove the `ContentSizeFitter` on the child elements, and have all the checkboxes checked both on the panel and the element's `HorizontalLayoutGroup`, except for the "force expand" ones. That works on a recent version of Unity -- I can't tell about yours (which seems to be outdated since I can see it's missing options)

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/197761/discussion-between-hugo-and-lloyd).

Comment: I think the main problem with all that is that the Text is a child gameobject of the Button, so all that automatic layouting doesnt really work out of the box.

Comment: @hugo sorry it's me here again! I was wondering if you had any thoughts if there's a way of setting up the buttons without me having to update to the newer version of Unity?

Comment: Oh waw, thank you @hugo. Just to check with you, would I call the LayoutRebuilder function immediately after creating the button themselves (in the `for` loop)? Would the call look something like this? `LayoutRebuilder.ForceRebuildLayoutImmediate(button.transform);`.I'm not enitrely sure what would be passed as the function argument... the button rect transform given it's the parent of the text component?

Comment: Honestly I haven't used this technique... mine was probably a wee more hacky since I didn't know about that. But try first on the text, then the button if it doesn't work, then the layout if still no luck. That way you will know the most efficient (working!) alternative.

Comment: @hugo sorry me here again! I'm not entirely sure how the method call fits into my script :/ I've tried it today but nothing seems to happen....do you have an idea where/how I would call it? I've got the snippet of code attached in my original post. Do I keep the content fitter and horizontal group layout for the buttons? I'd also keep the horizontal layour group for the parent panel too?

Comment: First, can you make the buttons behave correctly by tweaking them in the editor (no scripts) ?

Comment: I can get the buttons to appear with their respective texts but the layout all a mess :/

Comment: I know I could get it to work in older versions like you did more or less — content size fitters and horizontal layouts. can’t tell exactly now since it has changed

Comment: but forget about the relayout until you get this to work — the relayout is for when you change the texts dynamically and the UI does not follow

Comment: Ah right ok, hmmm. I guess I'm at that stage though... the button width do change size depending on amount of text within them but I just can't get rid of the spacing in-between :/ as the button text get changed dynamically as the game advances, I can't just 'hard-code' the spacing setting :/

Answer (score 1):

You could calculate the button's width manually like this. Dont use the LayoutGroup to control anything thats concerned with width though.
You might want to add some extra space, the buttons are very tightly packed, but I leave that up to you :D

```
using UnityEngine;
using UnityEngine.UI;

//Just to make sure its put on a button
[RequireComponent(typeof(Button))]
public class FitButtonSizeToText : MonoBehaviour
{
    RectTransform buttonTransform;
    Text buttonText;

    void Awake() {
        buttonTransform = GetComponent<RectTransform>();
        buttonText = GetComponentInChildren<Text>();
    }

    void Start() {
        FitButtonWidthToText();
    }    

    public void FitButtonWidthToText() {
        int widthOfTheText= 0;
        CharacterInfo characterInfo;
        foreach(char c in buttonText.text) {
            buttonText.font.GetCharacterInfo(c, out characterInfo, buttonText.fontSize);
            widthOfTheText += characterInfo.advance;
        }
        buttonTransform.sizeDelta = new Vector2(widthOfTheText, buttonTransform.sizeDelta.y);
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your code. I've just implemented it into my project but doesn't seem to do anything... basically I'm creating my buttons through a for loop initially. Then outside the loop I call your method. Do you think I'm going about it the right way?

Comment: The script is on the button prefab on the same gameobject the button component is on? Also the parent of the button should have a layout group (you can enable everything except anything that deals with width, thats what the script is for), but no content size fitter on either the parent, the button or the children.

Comment: But generally, you only need what I put in `FitButtonWidthToText()`, you can extract that code and use it whereever it fits. `widthOfTheText` is how much space the text (I pull it from the Text component, but you could pass it as argument aswell) will take up given a Font (which I also pull from the Text componen) at fontSize (set in the Text component). I can comment the script line by line if it helps you!?

Comment: Thanks for that. Hmmm ok so I made a script under the ButtonPrefab, copied your code into it, ensured the button parent had a Horizontal Layout Group (with Width's unchecked) but it didn't work :/ could it be that your script is being ran before my other script gets the chance to populate text into the buttons?

Comment: I just realized, I put the call to the function in `Awake` maybe move it to `Start` (I'll edit that in the answer aswell) and/or call it manually after you set up the Text.

Comment: Thanks. I called the function straight after setting up the button, ensured that the parent object had Horizontal Layout Group attached but unfortunately nothing did the trick :/

Comment: I've updated my original post with the code I have where I call your method

Comment: try `button.transform.SetParent(buttonPanel.transform, false);` instead. Also if you instantiate as `Button` right away and pass some of the stuff als argument, you save yourself a whole lot of `GetComponent` calls (= just a minor performance improvement, but first fix that they show up ^^). Also you should post code as text, then I would have posted code back, but I'm too lazy to type it out from the image :P

Comment: Oh no! I have no idea why I pasted the code as an image! So sorry! I'll update it now. I've changed the code with what you said above but still the same (blank result) :/

Comment: Nvm, I figured something out. I managed to get it working, but I dont get it to work your way. The problem seems to be that the Font is not fully initialized in the same frame as the button is instantiated and therefore characterInfo.advance always is 0. I turned my method into a coroutine and waited a frame before I did all the calculations and it worked flawlessly. What I would suggest is that you simply attach my above script to your button prefab and simply do `button.transform.SetParent(buttonPanel.transform, false)` when you instantiate. It works this way, I tested it.

Comment: Ok, there is something really odd happening now. The first time I run after I edited ANYTHING in the code, it does absolutely nothing (I added a comment lol). The second time, no problem whatsoever. What a weird behaviour, I have absolutely no idea why that happens now Oo

Comment: The problem with this is it does not work when I build it. The only way I get it to work with instantiating the buttons is when I do the calculations in a coroutine after waiting for a frame. Maybe its time for me to open my first question?!

Comment: I hope someone else can help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57446491/instantiate-a-button-in-a-layoutgroup-and-set-size-based-on-text-length-weirdnes

Comment: Ah that is a strange one.... thanks for your persistence with it though! Hopefully we'll get to the bottom of it soon :)